# Removing the leading and trailing newline characters

Tags: html, ruby, string

I am saving a text along with html tags. For e.g., if I enter `'What is your name?'`, it will be stored as `'<p>What is your name?</p>'` inside the table.

If take the same value to a report, it has an extra newline at the beginning and at the end of the string. I am outputting the value of  `@question.description` using the code `@question.description.html_safe`.

Kindly tell me a solution to trim out `"\n"` from the beginning and from the end of that paragraph string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String#strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip): *Returns a copy of str with leading and trailing whitespace removed.*

```
"\n what\r\n".strip
#=> "what"
```

If you want to change your variable, you need to do one of the following

```
s = "\nyour string\n"
s.strip!    # first option
s = s.strip # second option
```

Comment: This seems to have no effect on the string. So I think there would be a <p> tag at the beginning and </p> tag at the end of the paragraph string. As it is a PDF report, I couldn't check that. Kindly tell me how to remove those leading and trailing paragraph tags?

Comment: Read the function description, it *returns a copy*. You could even see an other function called `strip!` under `strip` if you read a bit the documentation.

Comment: I don't know why this is upvoted. This also removes whitespaces, and the OP asked about newlines.

Answer (score 1):

**To remove all html tags**
use [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) method

```
strip_tags('<p>What is your name?</p>')
```

**To remove only starting and ending `<p></p>` tag**

```
s = ' <p>What is <p> your</p> name?</p> '
s = s.strip.sub('<p>','').chomp('</p>')
#=> "What is <p> your</p> name?"
```

**To remove all `<p></p>` tags**

```
'<p>What is your name?</p>'.gsub(/<p>|<\/p>/,'')
```

Comment: If I want to remove only the <p> tag at the beginning and </p> at the end and no other tags?

Comment: `'\n<p>What is </p><p>your name?</p>\n'.strip!.gsub(/\A<p>|<\/p>\Z/, '')` — the example above will remove _all the para tags_.

Comment: I only want to remove the starting <p> tag and the last </p> tag. all the other tags needs to be there as it is. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a nice method for string called: [squish](http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish)
It removes new line characters from the middle of the string too.